# Using threads with structures

Tags: c

My goal is to create 3 threads, each one with a struct associated with it then let it print its content. 
I have this piece of code:

```
int main() {

  pthread_t threads[3];
  int threads_id[3];
  int i;

  typedef struct mythread{
    pthread_t tid;
    char string[];
  };

  for(i =0; i<3; i++) {
    threads_id[i] = i;
    struct mythread = {i, "This is the thread number"};
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_struct, &mythread);
  }

  for(i =0; i<3; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}

void* print_struct(void * arg) {
  struct *p1 = (struct*) arg;
  struct p2 = *p1;

  printf("%s", p2.string);
  printf(" ");
  printf("%d", p2.tid);


  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Buut it is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"it is not working"*.  What is actually happening? Compiler errors? Seg-faults? Incorrect output?

Comment: Plenty of errors
here you go: https://imgur.com/a/clfAI6A

Comment: There is no "alias" in your type alias, and no real address as the last arg to pthread_create. In your thread function, there's no *type* for `p1 or p2`. This code looks like sheer guessing from someone that's never coded C before, much less -pthreaded C. I concur with Ayre. Once you fix your code to compile and run, you're still going to have issues afterward (the massive thread startup race condition to reap value from the arg), but that's apparently awhile (maybe a semester?) off.

Comment: @WhozCraig You forgot to mention that the person above used 3 printf statements which are meant to be run as one statement. However the threads will interfere with each other causing printing errors

Comment: "_Plenty of errors here you go:_" -- copy-paste error messages _as text_ into the question body. Relevant error messages are part of the description of your problem; add as _text_ instead of as image to facilitate searching of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with just a bit of cleanup.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c -pthread \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>   // for printf()
#include <string.h>  // for strcpy()
#include <pthread.h> // for pthread_t, and related functions

// declare this type _before_ using it
typedef struct
{
  pthread_t tid;   // no need to store this in another array
  int id;          // just count the threads with an easy to read number
  char string[80]; // you forgot to give the size of the storage
} mythread;        // this way, ``mythread'' is a correct name for a type

void *
print_struct(void *arg)
{
  mythread *t=(mythread *)arg; // access a _single_ structure (out of 3)
  printf("%s %d\n", t->string, t->id); // display its properties
  pthread_exit(NULL); // I would have preferred a simple ''return NULL;''
}

int
main(void)
{
  mythread threads[3]; // everything will be stored here
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  {
    // each thread will use its own structure in the array (1 out of 3)
    threads[i].id=i; // the ``easy to display'' number
    strcpy(threads[i].string,            // provide each thread with its
           "This is the thread number"); // own message (the same here)
    pthread_create(&threads[i].tid, NULL,      // tid is updated
                   print_struct, &threads[i]); // only 1 structure (out of 3) 
  }
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  {
    pthread_join(threads[i].tid, NULL); // reuse the stored tid
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd consider commenting *in prose* about the nature of the problems you fixed, and how you fixed them?  Code-only answers are not usually worth the pixels it takes to display them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are perfectly right, sorry about that. I tried to put some comments but I'm not satisfied since they don't really illustrate the process of transforming the code (just the result). Should I delete?